# Connecting to Azure HDI cluster from a Windows machine using Hive ODBC?

Tags: azure, hive, odbc

How can I connect to an Azure HDInsight cluster from a Windows machine using a Hive ODBC connection ?. I have installed the Hive ODBC driver on my windows machine . What are the configuration settings on the ODBC driver I will need to connect to the HDInsight cluster in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Connect Excel to Apache Hadoop in Azure HDInsight with the Microsoft Hive ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver). This example includes instructions on how to configure the **Hive ODBC** driver to connect to an **Apache Haddop** in **Azure HDInsight**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I followed along the steps that was mentioned in the link , When I click Test , I get the following error   FAILED!

[Microsoft][Hardy] (34) Error from server: connect() failed: errno = 10060.

Comment: Make sure no firewall is blocking the connection on both sides (azure and the client machine)